# How to get validation test and training errors of a neural network?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have created and trained a neural network using the following code .I want to know how to get the training testing and validation errors/mis-classifications the way we get using the matlab GUI.

```
trainFcn = 'trainscg';  % Scaled conjugate gradient backpropagation.
% Create a Pattern Recognition Network
hiddenLayerSize = 25;
net = patternnet(hiddenLayerSize);
% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
net.divideParam.trainRatio = trainper/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = valper/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = testper/100; 
% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,x,t);
```

Comment: they are in decimals/negative due to rounding - you can just `round`them if you want.

Comment: @GameOfThrows so u r saying that my code is fine and I just need to round them off right?And no need to worry about the negative?

Comment: Well yeah, I don't know exactly what you are after, but your code is fine

Comment: @GameOfThrows thanks!

Comment: @GameOfThrows just one more doubt does increasing the number of neurons in the hidden layers gives more accurate results?In my case since it is 100 so if i increase it to 200 will it be more accurate?Although I think there might be some threshold value for a  particular application  after which the output may not be more accurate.

Comment: Not necessarily, it will certainly increase your computation cost, but number of neurons in each layer is much more dependent on your data; If you have an image of 20 by 20 pixels, there is no need to have neurons in the Input Layer of greater than 400. For the hidden layers, it really depends on the significance of your data, you can optimize the number of neurons in the hidden layers, but it requires iteration training to minimize error on a set of known/labelled test set.

Comment: @GameOfThrows hey can you pls answer this question .If possible just give me some suggestions on how to proceed